# Sending Mass Text with Twilio API

Tags: node.js, twilio, sms

I'm trying to set up a mass text by following this video exactly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMOYY58jyKk

When trying to run I receive this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wesleymoore/Downloads/Twilio Passthrough 
Friday/node_modules/node-env-run/dist/bin/node-env-run.js:21:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! passthrough@1.0.0 start: `nodenv .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

---

I've managed to use a more simple code of to send one email but I need mass emails sent. I'm not receiving anything in my logs so I'm not sure what the issue could be. Any help would be much appriciated. Or if possible can I use this code to add extra numbers since it seems to work:

```
var accountSid = '------------'; // Your Account SID from 
www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = '---------------';   // Your Auth Token from 
www.twilio.com/console

var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.create({
body: 'Hello from Node',
to: '+1usnumber',  // Text this number
from: '+1usnumber' // From a valid Twilio number
})
.then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are running that causes that error?

Answer (score 0):

to send bulk messages you need a recipient array and then loop over the array calling your function each time with a different number. as shown in the twilio docs https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-node-js?code-sample=code-send-an-sms-using-the-programmable-sms-api&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#send-a-message-to-multiple-recipients

Here's a snippet from the docs:

```
var numbersToMessage = ["+15558675310", "+14158141829", "+15017122661"]

numbersToMessage.forEach(function(number){
  var message = client.messages.create({
    body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
    from: '+16468635472',
    to: number
  })
  .then(message =>  console.log(message.status))
  .done();
});
```